# VKontakte Javascript SDK user email

Tags: javascript, email, sdk, vk

I'm integrating `VKontakte (VK.com)`login to a site because most of the client base there is russian and our usernames consist of email address'. I can get the user information via the `Javascript SDK` but it only contains

```
domain
first_name
href
id
last_name
nickname
```

I have actually gotten the app to ask for email permissions but it still won't get passed back to the site in the response. Can I even retrieve the email? The API documentation about it is very vaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working with VK API more than for 3 years and I can say with with absolute certainty that VK do`t allow any app to get such user information as email, mobile phone etc. There is no way to get this data

Comment: Very odd. We however came to this conclusion as well and added an extra step to our system. After logging in with VK you must insert your email address to continue. Thanks for the reply!